# what does "delay" mean when implementing StatefulJob?

Tags: java, jboss, seam, quartz-scheduler

i already know that when using quartz and we dont want concurrent jobs, we need to implement the StatefulJob and the jobs wont run simultaneously but i wanna know what does it mean that new triggers that occur before the completion of the execute(xx) method will be delayed? does it mean that once the job is completed, the one that is delayed is fired immediately or it will just be skipped and waiting for the next trigger?
also i want to keep a record for each trigger that is not fired because it was already running, so does quartz tell me this information in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Delayed" means that Quartz won't select the trigger for firing even though its next fire time has arrived.

Once the running job instance completes, the trigger will again be candidate for firing, and if the next fire time has arrived (or past) it will be fired.

The caveat to this is that the blocked trigger is subject to misfire handling.  If it is blocked for more time than your configured misfire threshold (defaults to 1 minute) then the trigger's misfire instruction will be applied, which depending upon which you selected for that trigger, may cause a skip in the trigger's firings, or may cause a rapid repeat (attempting to catch up).

You can implement a TriggerListener to be notified of misfires, but there is no event simply for a trigger being blocked from execution.

Comment: ohhh i see,so if i configure it to "MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING" the trigger will be skipped.
anyway i did some research on the TriggerListener and figured out what to do but when they say : "jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) is Called by the Scheduler when a JobDetail was about to be executed (an associated Trigger has occured), but a TriggerListener vetoed it's execution." what happens exactly? how can my application know that this function is called?

Comment: Your application would know that the function was called because your application is what implements the TriggerListener interface.

Comment: MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING does not cause a skip, it causes the next fire time to remain what it was (now in the past, if a misfire has occurred) - and therefore the trigger will fire ASAP when the running job that is blocking it completes.

Comment: the jobExecutionVetoed() method has nothing to do with misfires.  It has to do with a listener vetoing the execution.  The is an event/method on the listener specifically for misfires.

Comment: so what should i do if i want the trigger that is missed to be skipped and not fired after the running job that is blocking it completes?

Comment: That depends on the type of trigger, but they all have a misfire instruction that should do what you want.

Comment: hi again,
i noticed while browsing that the StatefulJob is deprecated and i should use the annotations:
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
the same question is : how in this case will i be informed that a trigger is skipped?